# ¿Como hacer operaciones de suma y divición en Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

Tengo una base de datos con los siguientes datos.

```
id  puntos  cambio
1    1000     1
2    2200     2
3    1500     1
4    3000     2
```

¿Como puedo hacer la operación de dividir puntos/cambio de cada registro y se sume el resultado de todos los registros en una consulta con eloquent? ejemplo: 1000/1 + 2200/2 + 1500/1 + 3000/2

Por el momento obtengo el valor con el siguiente código para obtener el valor que quiero, pero ¿quiero ver si puedo ahorrar el proceso del foreach?.

```
$sum_total_points = DB::table('users')
        ->select('puntos','cambio')
        ->where('empresa_id',session('empresa_id'))
        ->get();
        echo session('empresa_id');

        $total_cost = 0;
        foreach ($sum_total_points as $row) {
            if($row->cambio > 0){
                $total_cost = $total_cost + ($row->puntos/$row->cambio);
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?, recuerda que es importante leas [ask], por otro lado  ¿no alcanza con hacerlo con SQL puro?, sería bastante simple

Comment: El resultado que quiero lo obtuve con una consulta y luego usando un foreach para hacer las operaciones pero quiero saber si me puedo ahorrar todo ese proceso y hacerlo en una consulta.

Comment: Seguro que si, pero si no agregas aquello que hayas intentado tu pregunta quedará cerrada (*al momento llevas 2 de 3 votos para ello*)

Comment: Listo, gracias por el consejo ya edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considero que:

No requieres al query builder (**de manera inicial**) para resolver el problema planteado.

- Es decir si requieres calcular la multiplicación de: **puntos * cambio** alcanza con realizar lo siguiente:

  ```
  SELECT puntos * cambio AS Total 
  WHERE ................
  FROM users;
  ```

  - Ahora en este punto obtendrías (basándome en tu código) una salida similar a esta:

    ```
    Total
    ------
     1000
     4400
     1500
     6000
    ```
- Sin embargo ahora debemos realizar la sumatoria de esos valores calculados, por tanto igual con SQL lo resolvemos con la función de agregación *`SUM`* así:

  ```
  SELECT SUM(puntos * cambio) AS Total 
  WHERE ..............
  FROM users;
  ```

  - Lo anterior nos daría una salida como esta:

    ```
    Total
    -----
    12900
    ```
- Ahora a nivel de Laravel puedes construir la query de esta forma:

  ```
   DB::table('users')->selectRaw('SUM(puntos * cambio) AS Total')
       ->where('empresa_id',session('empresa_id'))
       ->value('Total');
  ```

Cuya salida sería algo como esto:

> "12900"

Comment: :O Muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba.